# Create Table If Not Exists Hanging

Tags: mysql, bash, amazon-web-services, create-table

I am still new to using databases, but currently I am using a mysql database and attempting to make my bash script unbreakable because it might be used in several different environments (dev, qa, etc). I know it will run correctly without this one line.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backupfiles (fileName VARCHAR(20), archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100), glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);
```

I also know that if I put that exact line into my database when that table does not exist then it runs perfectly and if it does exist already it gives me a warning, but does not break.

```
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                            |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1050 | Table 'backupfiles' already exists |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
```

When I run the line above and there is no table named backupfiles it works perfectly, but when there is it hangs(when I say hangs it sits there and does nothing) 95% of the time and 5% of the time works. Has anyone run into a problem like this? I am using AWS RDS(Amazon Web serices Relational Database Service) and the mysql server is  5.5.27

Here is all of my code that I relates to the mysql database

```
mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw <<QUERY_INPUT
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DATABASE;
use glacier;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backupfiles (fileName VARCHAR(20), archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100), glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);
INSERT INTO backupfiles VALUES ('$archive_file_name', '$archiveID', '$CURRENTVAULT', '$checkSum', CURDATE());
COMMIT;
QUERY_INPUT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is a working prototype, looking at improving it. For now if anyone else has this issue

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DATABASE;" > /tmp/runthis.sql
echo "use $DATABASE;" >> /tmp/runthis.sql
SQLSTMT="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE table_schema='${DATABASE}' AND table_name='backupfiles';"
TABLE_EXISTS=`mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
if [[ ${TABLE_EXISTS} -eq 0 ]]; then
  SQLSTMT="CREATE TABLE backupfiles (fileName VARCHAR(20),"
  SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100),"
  SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);"
  echo "${SQLSTMT}" >> /tmp/runthis.sql
fi
SQLSTMT="INSERT INTO backupfiles VALUES ('$archive_file_name',"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} '$archiveID', '$CURRENTVAULT', '$checkSum', CURDATE());"
echo "${SQLSTMT}" >> /tmp/runthis.sql
echo "COMMIT;" >> /tmp/runthis.sql
mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw < /tmp/runthis.sql
```